# Android OpenGL ES read PHONE inconsistant with EMULATOR

Tags: android, opengl-es, emulation

Hey,
i wrote a small application, a client application which receives images from a server, and then display them on a rotating cube using openGL ES.
this works just fine in the emulator, but on real phone SGS , blank white images displayed instead.
what could be the problem ???

the photos are saved using

```
     fos = openFileOutput(i+".jpg",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

and then read and converted to Bitmap using

```
     File myImage= context.getFilesDir();
     String imgPath=myImage.getAbsolutePath();

     BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(imgPath+"/"+face+".jpg");
     bitmap[face]= bmd.getBitmap();
```

The Rendering Code used is same as supposed in [Example 6a: Photo-Cube , under MYGLRenderer.java](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/Android_3D.html)

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds somewhat similar situation I faced some time ago. Reason was that I didn't resize Bitmap to size of power of two before sending it to GL context.

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/10829/loading-png-textures-for-use-in-android-opengl-es1

Comment: tried to send from server all photos with 512x512 resolution. still having the same problem, Also tried to resize Bitmap to power of two , didnt help ! any ideas ?

Comment: In that case, all I can think of is making a quick test with ImageView (or what ever comes in hand first) to see Bitmap is shown properly there.

Comment: Already Tried that, viewing with ImageView works fine. Did you look at the link I attached with the GL Renderer ?? might there be the problem ??

Comment: I don't know, only problem I've had so far with textures was this resizing I wasn't doing. And it showed exactly as you describe, worked for me on emulator, but got feedback it didn't work on device. Beyond that, when it comes to device specific issues, I'm very much clueless.